# WSDL to WADL conversion

Tags: rest, soap, wsdl, wadl

I need to convert a SOAP web service to a RESTful one.. The idea is to do so by converting the WSDL to a WADL..

Is it possible and what about the resulting service, does it encompass all the Service logic and won't I lose data doing that?

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying that just by converting one format to other your SOAP WS magically will become a RESTFULL one?

Comment: Even if you could convert your WSDL into a WADL that would not change a thing on your actual service. So why would you want to do that? Do you want to refactor your SOAP API as a RESTful one?

Comment: Yes I found this tool wsdl2rest.sourceforge.net that gives directly the restful ws from the wsdl file...

Comment: Yes I want to refactor a SOAP API for a mobile integration

Comment: could yo uget wsdl2rest to work?